# Passing json to List<Dictionary<string, string>> to method

Tags: c#, json, .net

We have below API method which I need to debug. The API is being called from a web which at this moment I dont have access to so dont know whats the exact format of params being passed.

In the mean time I want construct a json so that I can pass to this method and debug. But whatever I pass its always null. Could you please share what am I doing wrong

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData([FromBody] List<Dictionary<string, string>> data)
{
   //parse data here
}
```

The data param always comes out to be null, when I am passing below json. Since its null I cannot proceed further.

My swagger shows this is whats being expected but when I pass the same, it shows data param to be null:

```
[
  {
    "additionalProp1": "string",
    "additionalProp2": "string",
    "additionalProp3": "string"
  }
]
```

I have tried to modify the above json but keeps on saying null.
Any input what the correct json would be

Comment: Have you tried using an API tool such a postman to try to talk to the API first and foremost to see what response you get rather than having .net sit on top?

Comment: Are you certain that you are POSTing to the correct endpoint? My first guess would be you are doing a GET instead of a POST. My next guess would be you aren't calling the correct endpoint. As it is, the best I can do is guess since you haven't provided more details regarding how the request is made from the frontend.

Comment: if you don' t know format how do you know that it  is a list then?

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. This is an existing api which I want to debug. I am trying to run it from swagger and pass the json and it does hit the above endpoint but my data param is null. Since I dont have the access to my web project at the moment I wanted to just run the api and see what the json would look like.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't know what to expect, the safest way is

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData([FromBody] JToken data)
{
  //if you don't know
var json=data.ToString();
// or 
var prop1 = (string)data[0]["additionalProp1"];

// or it seems to me that you know what to expect
Dictionary<string,string>[] dict = data.ToObject<Dictionary<string,string>[]>();

}
```

the code will be working if you use Newtonsoft.Json

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;


services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
  options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

but I guess you can find analogical code for text.json

PS

Your action with a dictionary should be working too. I am afraid that you are creating a wrong http request or http request body. Post the code are you using

Answer (score 0):

You could try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`(data)

It sometimes works when `FromBody` attribute doesn't.

Comment: I very much doubt this would work. Within the function declaration the arguments should be types, not function calls. You can't call `DeserializeObject` as an argument type. If you make this call within the function body, `data` is already `null` according to the OP so it would also fail there.

Comment: This is just plastering over the issue though, if you can't get something to work, understanding why it doesn't work is important rather than trying to find a workaround that might be suboptimal